# Web scraping search with Python Beautifulsoup or Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a web crawler that is able to collect battle win/loss data from different superheroes from the website https://www.superherodb.com/battle/create/#close.

I have already scraped all the superhero names, I want to add each character individually and collect the data of their battle against all other characters. For example, Superman vs all, Thor vs all, etc... and collect data on the battles of each character vs all other characters.

For example, https://www.superherodb.com/superman-vs-thor/90-103/ contains stats on Superman vs Thor.

If possible, how can I also scrape the data in such an organized and clean fashion, that I can collect all the data in dict form for example: {"Superman_vs_Thor": [46, 2, 52]}, {"Superman_vs_Spiderman": [98, 2]}?

Comment: What code have you written so far? Please edit it into your original post.

Comment: I haven't written any code yet because I don't know where to start with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix up the .text sections on the win,loss,draw sections but to get the values you'd want you can append the values to an array also check if the section exists on the page and then grab the names you said you had by index into a dict.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
urls=['https://www.superherodb.com/superman-vs-thor/90-103/']
names=['Superman_vs_Thor']
complete_list={}
for indx,url in enumerate(urls):
    driver.get(url)
    battles=[]
    try:
        win=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='battle-team-result win']"))).text
        battles.append(win)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        draw=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='battle-team-result draw']"))).text
        battles.append(draw)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        loss=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='battle-team-result lose']"))).text
        battles.append(loss)
    except:
        pass
    complete_list[names[indx]]= battles

print(complete_list)
```

Gives this so far:

```
{'Superman_vs_Thor': ['912 wins (52%)', '35 (2%)', '806 wins (46%)']}
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you very much this WORKS! But how can I replicate this to all other superheroes. to generate the list of urls. How can I enter the names of other superheroes (I already have the complete list of all superheroes) in the battle creation section to get this result?

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't able to convert the info you need into a dict, but I was able to scrape them

here's the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.superherodb.com/superman-vs-thor/90-103/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

battle = soup.find('h1', class_='h1-battle')
superman = soup.find('div', class_='battle-team-result lose')
thor = soup.find('div', class_='battle-team-result win')
average = soup.find('div', class_='battle-team-result draw')

print('Battle:', battle.text)
print('Superman stats:', superman.text)
print('Thor stats:', thor.text)
print('Average:', average.text)
```

Comment: Upvote for providing a solution despite the OP not providing any code.

Comment: Logically you'd wait until the OP provides the code then provide an answer.

Comment: dict=[]->dict["keyvalue"] = [win,draw,lose] to set a dict if you'd like to know.

Comment: {"Superman_vs_Spiderman": [98, 2]} Also looking at this section you'd want to append to a list and if it doesn't exist then just don't append.

Comment: Thank you very much this WORKS! But how can I replicate this to all other superheroes. to generate the list of urls. How can I enter the names of other superheroes (I already have the complete list of all superheroes) in the battle creation section to get this result?

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

driver = driver  = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.superherodb.com/superman-vs-thor/90-103/")
title = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"h1-battle").text
characters = title.split("vs")
results = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"battle-team-result")

print('Title: ', title)

print(characters[0] + ': ' + results[0].text)
print('Draw: ', results[1].text)
print(characters[1] + ': ' + results[2].text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this WORKS! But how can I replicate this to all other superheroes. to generate the list of urls. How can I enter the names of other superheroes (I already have the complete list of all superheroes) in the battle creation section to get this result?